# How to iterate over this json String

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In this fiddle attempting to iterate over json String :

http://jsfiddle.net/sfbanvv6/2/

But receive exception  :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token e
```

JSON is valid ? So something incorrect with how I'm iterating ?

fiddle code :

```
javascript : 

jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

    var jsonString2 = '{ "header": "test1", "children": [ { "date": "2015-01-02", "count": "36" }, { "date": "2015-01-03", "count": "29" } ] }'

var data2 = []
var combinedHeights2=[]
var myData2 = JSON.parse(jsonString2);
$.each(myData2, function(i, obj) {
    console.log($.parseJSON(obj))
    $.each(obj.children, function(i2, obj2) {
    console.log('here')
        var d = new Date(obj2.date)
    console.log(Date.parse(d))
   // data2.push([Date.parse(d), parseInt(obj.count)])
   // combinedHeights2.push(parseInt(obj.count))
    });
});

    });
```

Comment: Add `console.log(obj)` and you will see why `JSON.parse(obj)` throws.

Comment: You are trying to iterate objects that are not arrays. For example - "header" holds a String object which can not be iterated. what are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [chrome logging formats](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consolelogobject-object) you can more clearly see what you are iterating with by changing your logging statement to;

```
$.each(myData2, function(i, obj) {
    console.log('%s %O', i, obj);
});
```

Your first `obj` is property in the loop `header = 'test1'` there is no `children` property for this. The second is `children = [ ]` which is your array.

To iterate over the array just use;

```
$.each(myData2.children, function(i, obj) {
  var d = new Date(obj.date)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.parseJSON(obj)` is attempting to parse something that is already parsed. JSON parsers don't parse only the top level and leave the inner JSON as JSON, they return an entire nested set of arrays and objects. So your error may be caused by your logging code.

The cure is to recognize that `obj` doesn't need any parsing and you can just use it directly.

Getting more specific, this code will do what you seem to want:

```
var jsonString2 = '{ "header": "test1", "children": [
    { "date": "2015-01-02", "count": "36" },
    { "date": "2015-01-03", "count": "29" }
] }';

var data2 = [];
var combinedHeights2 = [];
var myData2 = JSON.parse(jsonString2);
console.log(myData2);
$.each(myData2.children, function(i, obj) {
    console.log(obj);
    var d = new Date(obj.date);
    console.log(Date.parse(d));
});
```

Especially pay attention to what `myData2` looks like when logged. You need to use `myData2.children` in your `each`, not `myData2` by itself.

P.S. Get some semicolons!

Comment: reason I'm attempting to parse to json String is to discover what data is available on the object as unable to access the "header" or "children" properties as in http://jsfiddle.net/sfbanvv6/6/

Comment: My point is still valid. You can't re-parse an already parsed string because it's an object now.

Answer (score 0):

obj.children was undefined. Here its the working one

```
var myData2 = JSON.parse(jsonString2);
$.each(myData2, function(i, obj) {
        var t = myData2.children;   
        $.each(t, function(i2, obj2) {
        console.log(obj2);
        //var d = new Date(obj2.date);
    //console.log(Date.parse(d));
   // data2.push([Date.parse(d), parseInt(obj.count)])
   // combinedHeights2.push(parseInt(obj.count))
    });
});
```

but here is a better version to get only dates

```
$.each(myData2.children, function(i, obj) {
            var t = this;
            console.log(t.date);
          var d = new Date(t.date);

    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to iterate the children property of your Json then you can do it this way:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    
var jsonString2 = '{ "header": "test1", "children": [ { "date": "2015-01-02", "count": "36" }, { "date": "2015-01-03", "count": "29" } ] }'

var myData2 = JSON.parse(jsonString2);
$.each(myData2.children, function(i, obj) {
      
        console.log(obj);
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You were getting the exception because your code tried to iterate over your "header" parameter which holds a String and therefor cannot be iterated.